# How do i upload multiple images in Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, .net-core

I am trying to upload multiple images of a student. I want to save filenames in Database and upload images in www/studentimages directory. however with the method i have tried i am able to upload multiple image but only it only saves the name of last selected image in database.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> NewStudent(Student p)
        {
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
            foreach (var Image in files)
            {
                if (Image != null && Image.Length > 0)
                {
                    var file = Image;
                    var uploads = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/studentimages");
                    if (file.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse
                            (file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

                        System.Console.WriteLine(fileName);
                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                            p.Image = file.FileName;
                        }
                   }
                }
            }
             _context.Students.Add(p);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        } 


***My Student Class***

using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace PhotoUpload.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public List<string> Image{get;set;}

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share Student class

Answer (score 0):

you are overriding the student Image on every loop,
change

```
p.Image = file.FileName;
```

to

```
p.Image = p.Image +"-"+ file.FileName;
```

so this will save the student with all the file names separated by a "-".

If you want to show your student images you need to get your filenames separated again, you can achieve that with split()

```
string[] filenames = p.Image.Split('-');
```

this will return an array of strings that contains your filenames.

As you dont have a list of images in your model you shoul do the split in the view with razor code:

```
@foreach (var filename in Model.Image.Split('-'))
{
<img src="PathWhereImageIsSave/@filename"  alt="" />
}
```

to make it clear, this method is not the best, the filename can contain an '-' inside an will make the split fail, my recommendation is that if you will have a student with many images you should create a table of files with a relation to your student table, then do something like Erdi said

Comment: i am getting all the images name appended in database. How can i display those images in view

Answer (score 0):

Change in your class

```
public string  Image {get;set;}
```

to

```
public List<string> Image{get;set;}
```

and change it in controller

```
p.Image = file.FileName;
```

to

```
p.Image = new List<string>();
p.Image.Add(file.Filename)
```

I think it can help you. If not I need your Student class for helping you.

for displaying in view

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Image)
{
    <img src="~/studentimages/@item.Filename" />
}
```

You need to edit this for your wiev code

Comment: I am getting NullReferenceException on ``` p.Image.Add(file.Filename) ```

Comment: I edit for NullReferenceException and add for display view code

Comment: my student class `using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace PhotoUpload.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public List<string> Image{get;set;}
        
    }
}`

Comment: erdi yılmaz I am also getting this error, " The property 'Student.Image' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List<string>' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type"

Comment: I change Image to Model.Image